# PHP DOM removing empty elements as well as others

Tags: php, dom

The objective is to remove empty HTML elements such as `<div class="footer-1"></div>`

```
    <div class="inside-footer">
                            <div class="footer-1">
            </div>
<div class="someotherclass">somecontent</div>
</div>
```

As a test, the code currently is; The intention is to expand this for the entire DOM.

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $libxml_previous_state = libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $output = $dom->loadHTML($output, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    libxml_use_internal_errors( $libxml_previous_state );
    $xpath = new \DOMXpath( $dom );
    
    $html_root = $xpath->query( "/descendant::div" );
    
    foreach ( $html_root as $html_attribute ) {
        $trimmed_value = trim($html_attribute->nodeValue);
        
        if (empty($trimmed_value) && !in_array($html_attribute->nodeName, array('area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'command', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr'))) {
          $html_attribute->parentNode->removeChild($html_attribute);
        }
      }
```

This however appears to remove other `<div>` elements such as `<div class="someclass"><img src="somepath" /></div>` as well as hidden `<div>` similar to `<div class="htmlform"><input name="someinput" value="" type="hidden"></div>`

What does the code need to be updated to so that other elements are not removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that those `div` elements have no text content, so `empty($trimmed_value)` is true, and your `in_array` check will always fail since `$html_attribute->nodeName` will always be `div`, which is not in your list. Instead, check that there is only one `childNode` of the `div` and that it is an empty `#text` node:

```php
foreach ( $html_root as $html_attribute ) {
    $trimmed_value = trim($html_attribute->nodeValue);
    if ($html_attribute->childNodes->length === 0 ||
        $html_attribute->firstChild->nodeName === '#text' && 
        $html_attribute->childNodes->length === 1 && 
        empty($trimmed_value)) {
         $html_attribute->parentNode->removeChild($html_attribute);
    }
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3WWWs)

If you want this to remove empty elements from the entire DOM (using an xpath of `//*`), add a check for [`void` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#syntax-elements) to the beginning of the loop to prevent them being deleted too:

```php
foreach ( $html_root as $html_attribute ) {
    if (in_array($html_attribute->nodeName, array('area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'command', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr'))) continue;
    $trimmed_value = trim($html_attribute->nodeValue);
    if ($html_attribute->childNodes->length === 0 ||
        $html_attribute->firstChild->nodeName === '#text' && 
        $html_attribute->childNodes->length === 1 && 
        empty($trimmed_value)) {
         $html_attribute->parentNode->removeChild($html_attribute);
    }
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2VRMY)

Note that this will still delete empty `textarea` inputs, and also self-closing `SVG` tags e.g. `path` (or *any* other self-closing tags that may happen to be in the DOM). To avoid that, you should add those tags to the  array in the `in_array` check.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense if empty($trimmed_value) always returns true since the div tags have no content. I am not clear as to why !in_array would fail since it's meant to validate that the node is not one of the void elements which would be true since div is not. Since the div tag could have numerous child nodes, what would you recommend? Secondly can this be expanded to cover the entire DOM for any element that is empty so the query path would be $html_root = $xpath->query( "//*" ); instead?

Comment: @Motivated the `in_array` returns false because `$html_attribute` points to a `div` (your xpath query only returns `div` elements), so `$html_attribute->nodeName` is always `'div'`. This code should work for any empty node as you describe.

Comment: Thanks. Righto. `in_array` returning `false` is expected since it's intended to cater for the query once it's expanded to the entire. I take it that `if ($html_attribute->childNodes->length === 1 ` isn't needed to allow nested elements.

Comment: You do still need `$html_attribute->childNodes->length === 1` as that will prevent deletion of any element which has more than one child (which an element which contains only text will not have)

Comment: When you say as that will prevent deletion of any element which has more than one child (which an element which contains only text will not have), do you mean that an element that only contains text won't have more than one child? If yes, it isn't clear to me why since an element such as `div` can only have text with multiple children.

Comment: An element that only contains text has by definition only one child, the `#text` node that includes *all* of the text in the element. A `div` does not need to have multiple children to contain text - for example your `<div class="footer-1">` and `<div class="someotherclass">` both have only one child which is a text node.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something. If I have `<div><div class='1'>sometext</div><div class='2'>nexttext</div><div class='3'></div></div>` which may have multiple nodes that either have text or no text, I am not clear as to the definition of one child the parent `div` in this sample has 3 children.

Comment: That is correct. And the divs with class 1 and 2 have one child, and the div with class 3 has no children. Which has pointed out an error in the answer which I have fixed, since it didn't deal with that (no children) scenario. So for that sample data, the code will remove `<div class='3'></div>`

Comment: Righto. I didn't realize that the text between each `div` element is considered to be a child. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If the query is expanded to the entire DOM, it deletes, `meta`, `link`, `input`, `path`, `img`, `br`, `script` elements

Comment: If you use `//*` as the xpath, that will delete any empty elements. If you only want to delete empty `div` elements, use `//div`

Comment: Thanks. It shouldn't delete `meta`, `link` and the other elements though as they are not empty.

Comment: If you have a range of empty elements you want to delete, add something like `if (!in_array($html_attribute->nodeName, array('div', 'input'))) continue;` to the beginning of the `for` loop, where the array contains the element types you want to delete

Comment: They are "empty" as they have no child nodes, the only information in them is attributes.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore all tags that don't having closing tags or attributes? Wouldn't that be a better solution? So it would delete any empty element that has no attributes & no text or attributes and no text as an example.

Comment: There's no way to distinguish a self-closing tag (e.g. `img`) from one that requires a closing tag (e.g. `div`).

Comment: Couldn't void elements be ignored - https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html as generally self-closing tags only allow attributes and no content?

Comment: Thanks. Oddly it still deletes `path`, `textarea` unless these are added to the array as well. Any ideas as to why these would be removed?

Comment: `textarea` can have text content (the input value). `path` is a self-closing SVG tag so not included in the HTML self-closing tags. If you want to ignore them as well you would have to add them to the list.

Comment: Thanks. You have been awesome. I was at my wits end.

Comment: If you have any expertise in CSS, your help would be great - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376425/css-width-100-height-auto-gtmetrix-google-web-dev-properly-size-images. No one seems to have answered it.

Comment: @Motivated sorry, that's outside my area of expertise. You could try offering a bounty. Or perhaps delete and re-ask the question, but make sure you also include the `html` tag, it will get seen by more people that way. It would also be helpful if you included enough html to make a snippet to demonstrate the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Any chance you could help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742235/parsing-html-php-domdocument-loadhtml-utf-8-encoding? It may be up your alley.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227132/discussion-between-nick-and-motivated).